# While computing signature matrix in min hashing, can I take nth row of the permutation P in which document d has value 1?

Tags: data-mining, hashing

I am learning about some techniques to find similarity between documents. One of the methods is Min Hashing. According to Min Hashing we can find a signature matrix given a random permutation, P. According to this technique in order to calculate signature matrix, we have to take the index of the first row in which document d has value 1.

Is it necessary to do that? If so, then can anyone please explain why?
If not, can we take any nth row of boolean matrix permutation P?

Comment: The hash value should depend on the document somehow... MinHash has a relation to Jaccard similarity, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash#Jaccard_similarity_and_minimum_hash_values). If you use a different rule you won't necessarily get the same relation.